# Python script not reading GPIO

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run the following python script (mission_buttons.py) in the background of my RPi. Its purpose is to wait for input on two physical buttons (GPIO pin 23 and 24) and upon reading a logic HI on either pin, print the letter 'x' to the terminal or call updateMission.js.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import subprocess

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

upload_mission = GPIO.input(23)
execute_mission = GPIO.input(24)

while(1):

    if execute_mission == True:
        print 'x'

    if upload_mission == True:
        subprocess.call(["node", "/home/pi/QRIDrone/RPIBuild/updateMission.js"], shell=False)
```

But when I run the script, pressing the pushbuttons doesn't seem to do anything. 
If I adjust the code to this:

```
if execute_mission == False:
    print 'x'

if upload_mission == False:
    subprocess.call(["node", "/home/pi/QRIDrone/RPIBuild/updateMission.js"], shell=False)
```

the program prints x and calls updateMission.js repeatedly as it should. Is there something blocking the RPi from reading the GPIO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. check if You connected the right pins
2. You are not reading upload_mission = GPIO.input(23) in while. You just read it once before and then not
   You need:

   ```
   upload_mission = GPIO.input(23)
   execute_mission = GPIO.input(24)
   while(1):
       upload_mission = GPIO.input(23)
       execute_mission = GPIO.input(24)
       if execute_mission == True:
           print 'x'

       if upload_mission == True:
           subprocess.call(["node", "/home/pi/QRIDrone/RPIBuild/updateMission.js"], shell=False
   ```

Comment: Yep! You were right, moving those lines into the while loop worked. So now when I run the program from the command line it works fine! Thank you! Now I need to figure out why its not running automatically on startup even though I added it to rc.local...